# Performing Segue from AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to perform a segue after getting a notification.

Here is what I have in my app delegate.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {


            let viewController = self.window!.rootViewController!.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController")
            self.window?.rootViewController = viewController


    }
```

This takes me directly to the view I would like it to go to, however the navbar and tab bar are hidden. From the app delegate, how do I perform a segue from one view to another? So that I can reach by second view as if I had pushed from my first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with:

```
viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("my_segue_identifier", sender: nil)
```

Also the more robust way is to broadcast a NSNotification from your AppDelegate and have your viewcontroller listen for a specific notification.

Comment: I removed the self.window? line and added what you suggested, with my segue identifier, and the segue is not being performed.

Comment: How would I broadcast a NSNotification? Is there good tutorial on this?

Comment: Here's one example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-post-messages-using-nsnotificationcenter

Comment: Thank you, you are right!! Broadcasting the notification is the right way to go!

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
add public variable in AppDelegate (etc. flag =1)

```
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("User Info = ",response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    flag = 1;   <---
    completionHandler()
}
```

and check the flag on rootviewcontroller-> ViewDidLoad. if it's true ? call your spesific segue

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if (flag == 1) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "roottanBildirimSegue", sender: self)
    }
```