# Perform segue from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I need to perform a segue from the AppDelegate when the user has left the app in the background for more than three minutes.
This is my code:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let time_in = preferences.object(forKey: "time_background") as! Date
    let timenow = Date().addingTimeInterval(-3*60) as Date
    if time_in <= timenow {
        print("timeout")
        //transition to the login
    }
    print(preferences.object(forKey: "session_time") ?? "test")
}
```

So at *//transition to the login* I want the segue to bring the user back to the login page.

But I don't understand how to do a segue from the AppDelegate.

Comment: try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33983275/4056108)

Comment: This question has many different (right) answers because it depends of how is your app designed. Is your app a TabBar root controller or it's a NavController root controller? Is your app presenting Modal views and pushing view controllers or only push and pop controllers? Depends of these questions the best answer for you would be to create a notification to send to your controllers and dismiss or pop, or maybe it just use popToRootVC. Even present your login screen modally. Could you explain how is your app designed to provide you the most accurate answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func showLoginScreen(){
    let loginVC = UIStoryboard.getMainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewControllerIdentifier") as! LoginViewController

    UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.rootViewController = loginVC     
}

extension UIStoryboard{
    //returns storyboard from default bundle if bundle paased as nil.
    public class func getMainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard{
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Even though code is welcomed in answers, code-only answers are usually discouraged. Please include some explanation of what your code does and how it solves OP's problem.

Comment: The code is generally working for me. But when I do the function is called and I see the view Controller, but there is no navigation anymore. So it seems like I need to call the navigation Controller of the LoginViewController. But how would I do that?

Comment: Ok, I now got it to work:

`let loginVC= IStoryboard.getMainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainController")UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.rootViewController = loginVC `

@viktor-gardart @aura-abhishek
But a different answere suggested using `window?.rootViewController = loginVC` instead. Where is the difference in using this methode?

Comment: @BeatzCrathe another answer suggested by @ viktor-gardart is same as of mine. If you want navigation controller then assign navigation controller as rootViewController.     `let navigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationControllerIdentifier") as? UINavigationController; 
let viewControllers:[UIViewController] = NSArray.init(object: loginController) as! [UIViewController];
 navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers; 
 UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.rootViewController = navigationController;`

Answer (score 1):

I dont think attempting to use a segue would be the right way to go about this. firstly you would need to get the current root view controller that is displayed and push your login view controller onto the stack.

I think your best option would be to set the root view controller to your login view controller and then when the user authenticates you set the root view controller to be the navigation controller for your application. This will reset the view hierarchy/stack and will prevent issues with memory, hiding back buttons so the user can't just skip the login VC etc

In my application I have two custom navigation controllers. One for authentication related vc's and one for the main application. I just swap out the `window.rootViewController` as and when needed

In my AppDelegate I have

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

if authenticationManager.authenticated() {
    self.initialiseMainStack()
} else {
    self.initialiseAuthenticationStack()
}

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and then a little later down the file..

```
func initialiseMainStack() {
    let nav = UINavigationController()
    let vc = MainViewController()
    nav.setViewControllers([vc])
    self.window.rootViewController = nav
}

func initialiseAuthenticationStack() {
    let nav = UINavigationController()
    let vc = AuthViewController()
    nav.setViewControllers([vc])
    self.window.rootViewController = nav
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you could save a reference to the currently displayed `viewcontroller` and the perform the segue on that one.

Or you could just replace the `window` with the `LoginViewController`.

`window?.rootViewController = loginViewController`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how difficult is your app structure, but you can create an observer and send notification to every relevant instantiated viewcontroller from where you can navigate the user to login screen.